# Gridview with random image

Tags: java, android

How can I make `Gridview` animation with image view random image? `Gridview` animation already make it, so how can I put random image? sorry if i update this, with gridview with limitation show can do it?

It should work like following: When we enter the fun class, it will show gridview with random image

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/Fun"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@color/material_deep_teal_500"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context="com.app.aditya.pecs.Fun">

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridFu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:columnWidth="50dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/expanded_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

Grid View XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5dp"
android:weightSum="1">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/grid_image"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp">
</ImageView>
```

Fun Class

```
private GridView gridFu;
private Animator mCurrentAnimator;
private int mShortAnimationDuration;

// Create Array thumbs resource id's:
private int Fun[] = { R.drawable.cherry, R.drawable.dragonfruit,
        R.drawable.mango, R.drawable.orange,};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fun);

    // Initialize the variables:
    gridFu = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridFu);

    // Set an Adapter to the ListView
    gridFu.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    // Set on item click listener to the ListView
    gridFu.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos,
                                long id) {

            // Display the zoomed in image in full screen
            zoomImageFromThumb(v, Fun[pos]);

        }
    });

    // Set the Animation time form the android defaults
    mShortAnimationDuration = getResources().getInteger(
            android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

}

// Create an Adapter Class extending the BaseAdapter
class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public ImageAdapter(Fun activity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return Fun.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // Inflate the item layout and set the views
        View listItem = convertView;
        int pos = position;
        if (listItem == null) {
            listItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_view, null);
        }

        // Initialize the views in the layout
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);

        // Set the views in the layout
        iv.setBackgroundResource(Fun[pos]);

        return listItem;
    }

}

private void zoomImageFromThumb(final View thumbView, int imageResId) {

    if (mCurrentAnimator != null) {
        mCurrentAnimator.cancel();
    }


    final ImageView expandedImageView = (ImageView)    findViewById(R.id.expanded_image);
    expandedImageView.setImageResource(imageResId);


    final Rect startBounds = new Rect();
    final Rect finalBounds = new Rect();
    final Point globalOffset = new Point();

    thumbView.getGlobalVisibleRect(startBounds);
    findViewById(R.id.PhotoFruit).getGlobalVisibleRect(finalBounds,
            globalOffset);
    startBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y);
    finalBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y);


    float startScale;
    if ((float) finalBounds.width() / finalBounds.height() > (float) startBounds
            .width() / startBounds.height()) {
        // Extend start bounds horizontally
        startScale = (float) startBounds.height() / finalBounds.height();
        float startWidth = startScale * finalBounds.width();
        float deltaWidth = (startWidth - startBounds.width()) / 2;
        startBounds.left -= deltaWidth;
        startBounds.right += deltaWidth;
    } else {
        // Extend start bounds vertically
        startScale = (float) startBounds.width() / finalBounds.width();
        float startHeight = startScale * finalBounds.height();
        float deltaHeight = (startHeight - startBounds.height()) / 2;
        startBounds.top -= deltaHeight;
        startBounds.bottom += deltaHeight;
    }


    thumbView.setAlpha(0f);
    expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    expandedImageView.setPivotX(0f);
    expandedImageView.setPivotY(0f);


    AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
    set.play(
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.X,
                    startBounds.left, finalBounds.left))
            .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.Y,
                    startBounds.top, finalBounds.top))
            .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_X,
                    startScale, 1f))
            .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_Y,
                    startScale, 1f));
    set.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration);
    set.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            mCurrentAnimator = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            mCurrentAnimator = null;
        }
    });
    set.start();
    mCurrentAnimator = set;


    final float startScaleFinal = startScale;
    expandedImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mCurrentAnimator != null) {
                mCurrentAnimator.cancel();
            }


            AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
            set.play(
                    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.X,
                            startBounds.left))
                    .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.Y,
                            startBounds.top))
                    .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView,
                            View.SCALE_X, startScaleFinal))
                    .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView,
                            View.SCALE_Y, startScaleFinal));
            set.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration);
            set.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
            set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    thumbView.setAlpha(1f);
                    expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mCurrentAnimator = null;
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                    thumbView.setAlpha(1f);
                    expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mCurrentAnimator = null;
                }
            });
            set.start();
            mCurrentAnimator = set;
         }
       });
   }
   }
```

Comment: i m stuck at how to random image

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code in your Fun class:

```
// Set on item click listener to the ListView
gridFu.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos,
                            long id) {

        // Display the zoomed in image in full screen
        zoomImageFromThumb(v, Fun[pos]);

    }
});
```

with this new code:

```
// Set on item click listener to the ListView
gridFu.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    private Random random = new Random();

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos,
                            long id) {

        // Display the zoomed in image in full screen
        zoomImageFromThumb(v, Fun[random.nextInt(Fun.length)]);

    }
});
```

This works by using a [`java.util.Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) to generate a random number between 0 and the length of your `Fun` array.

Comment: hmm @Pokechu22 when i change this code and want zoom it says error

Comment: when i click the image, the app stop responding